# How to create waveform display to mimic real time data acquisition?

Tags: real-time, labview, waveform

I have a csv file with pressure data. It is a single column of numbers. I want to display it in labview waveform chart in such a way that it appears as if data is being acquired in real time, something like how the output of Simulate signal vi looks. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Read From Spreadsheet File.vi` in tandem with some array primitives. Using the sample data from [this Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FJWfyYQ20dSXMeywGYArEBZDAbVLSreeoS9eQ4k6aAc/edit?usp=sharing), here is a comparison with `Simulate Signal.vi`:

[image]

### Block Diagram

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It certainly was what I was looking for.